# struts2 onblur server side ajax validation

Tags: ajax, struts2, struts2-jquery

How would I implement AJAX validation in struts2 which lets you know if a username is available onblur? This is what I've managed so far but the docs aren't clear:

JSP:

```
<%@ page
    language="java"
    contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib
    prefix="s"
    uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib
    prefix="sj"
    uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<sj:head jqueryui="true" />
<!-- Don't forget these 2 files!! -->
<script
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/struts/utils.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/struts/css_xhtml/validation.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="js/register.js"></script>
<title>Register</title>
</head>

<s:url
    action="loginLink"
    var="loginHREF" />
<s:url
    action="forgotPasswordLink"
    var="forgotPasswordHREF" />
<s:url
    action="Register"
    var="registerHREF" />
<body>

    <s:form
        theme="css_xhtml"
        action="Register"
        onsubmit="return myValidate()">
        <s:textfield
            name="user.username"
            label="Username"
            id="uname"
            required="true"
            pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{5,12}"
            title="5-12 Alphanumeric characters required" />
        <s:textfield
            name="user.email"
            label="Email"
            required="true" />
        <s:password
            id="pass1"
            name="user.password"
            label="Password"
            required="true"
            pattern="{5,12}"
            title="5-12 characters" />
        <s:password
            id="pass2"
            label="Confirm Password"
            required="true"
            pattern="{5,12}" />
        <s:textfield
            name="user.firstName"
            label="First Name"
            required="true" />
        <s:textfield
            name="user.lastName"
            label="Last Name" />
        <sj:datepicker
            yearRange='-90:-3'
            changeYear="true"
            name="user.birthDate"
            readonly="true"
            label="Date of Birth" />
        <s:submit value="Register" />
    </s:form>
    <s:a href="%{loginHREF}">Login</s:a>
    <s:a href="%{forgotPasswordHREF}">Forgot Password</s:a>

    <script>
        $("#uname").blur(function() {

            var fieldData = $("#uname").serialize();
            fieldData = fieldData.slice(5);
            //do the POST thingies
            $.ajax({

                type : "POST",
                url : "ValidateUsername",
                cache : false,
                data : fieldData,
                dataType : "json",
                complete : function(request) {
                    alert("In complete");
                    var form = $('form');

                    //clear previous validation errors, if any
                    //StrutsUtils.clearValidationErrors(form);

                    //get errors from response
                    var text = request.responseText;
                    alert(text);
                    var errorsObject = StrutsUtils.getValidationErrors(text);

                    //show errors, if any
                    if (errorsObject.fieldErrors) {
                        StrutsUtils.showValidationErrors(form, errorsObject);
                    }

                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Action:

```
@Action("ValidateUsername")
@Results(value = { @Result(name = "success", type = "json"), @Result(name = "input", type = "json") })
@ParentPackage("default")
@InterceptorRef("jsonValidationWorkflowStack")
public class ValidateUsername extends ActionSupport {

    private String username;

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate() {
        UserService service = new UserService();
        User isTaken = service.findByUsername(username);
        service.close();
        if (isTaken != null)
            addFieldError("user.username", "That username is taken");
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

The docs make it seem like struts2 will handle it for you if you simply add the json interceptor and set validate="true" in the sx:submit tag.
In register.js I check to see that password and confirmation password match. 
Basically I would like it to validate even before submit is pressed. Right now On submit it validates it like any other normal form.

Edit: Also, is there a working method other than using dojo? It seems to block all my client side validation including the required attributes, js, etc.

Edit2:I ditched the dojo plugin, learnt some js and managed to put together what i have now. Now the only thing left is to display an error. Alerting the response text shows up a json string with only a username key value pair in it. Should i add another member to the action and process it to display an error message? because the StrutsUtils js is not working. <strike>`addFieldError("user.username", "That username is taken");` does not modify the json result.</strike>

<strike>**Basically, how can i add fielderrors to my json response?**</strike>

Edit: I got my action to add my field errors to the json response by modifying the annotations as follows:

```
@Action("ValidateUsername")
@Results(value = {
        @Result(name = "success", type = "json"),
        @Result(name = "input", type = "json", params = { "ignoreHierarchy",
                "false", "includeProperties",
                "actionErrors.*,actionMessages.*,fieldErrors.*" }) })
@ParentPackage("default")
@InterceptorRef("jsonValidationWorkflowStack")
```

Now the only problem is in:
//clear previous validation errors, if any

```
**//StrutsUtils.clearValidationErrors(form);**

                        //get errors from response
                        var text = request.responseText;
                        alert(text);
                        **var errorsObject = StrutsUtils.getValidationErrors(text);**

                        //show errors, if any
                        if (errorsObject.fieldErrors) {


StrutsUtils.showValidationErrors(form, errorsObject);
                        }
```

None of the StrutsUtils functions are working. When i uncomment clearValidationErrors it does nothing and breaks the rest of the js code. errorsObject is empty and showValidation does nothing even though on printing my jon response i can see a field error with a message. **How do i get StrutsUtils to work?**

Also, is there a better way to implement my use case? I haven never learnt jquery/ajax and this is my first struts2 application.

Answer (score 0):

Struts is available server-side. You are trying to call

`var errorsObject = StrutsUtils.getValidationErrors(text);` in the client-side.

`StrutsUtils` is a class and is not available on client-side/javascript.

There are various ways through which you can send errors.

Please refer my answer in the below link, on how to handle ajax request & response when using struts2.

[How to get Ajax response in Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511259/how-to-get-ajax-response-in-struts2/20512226#20512226)