# How to get Ajax response in Struts2

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts2

I have refered this link [Ajax action calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408257/sending-data-from-jsp-to-struts2-action-class-using-jquery-ajax) But I am not able to 
Hi making an action call using ajax.
here is my code.

```
   $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            url:'ajaxAction?ajax_docno='+entry1+'-'+entry2+'-'+entry3+'-'+entry4,
        success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR)
                   {
                     if(jqXHR.status==200)
                        alert("success");
                      }
                     if(jqXHR.status==500)
                       {
                           alert("Fail");
                          }
               }


               }
                   );
```

**MY STRUTS.XML**

```
 <action name="ajaxAction" class="com.AjaxActionClass" method="checkExistence" > 
        <result name="success" type="httpheader">
                <param name="status" >200</param>
        </result>
        <result name="fail" type="httpheader">
                <param name="status" >500</param>
        </result>

    </action>
```

**In MY ACTION class**

```
 public  String checkExistence()
   {
        //DB checkup
         if exists return success;
         if not exists return fail;
       }
```

THis  is working fine

In my action class I am checking data existence in DB and returning some value to jSP to show the message.

My problem is how to pass a variables to jsp to show some `alert` message to USER if Data is not In DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reply I dont whats wrong with your answer but I am able to do that now using following code

```
  $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        url:'ajaxAction?ajax_docno='+entry1+'-'+entry2+'-'+entry3+'-'+entry4,
      statusCode:{500:function(){alert("The document number is alredy Exist");},
                        200:function(){alert("Good Work !! You can proceed.");}                     }


           }
               );
```

Answer (score 2):

There 3 ways :

Either you can send the JSP or JSON or just status-codes.

**JSP**

```
$.ajax({
...
success:function(data){
    alert(data);            //In case of JSP
}

<action name="myaction" class="actions.MyAction">
    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**JSON**

```
$.ajax({
...
success:function(data){
    var json=eval(data);       //Untested, but should give an idea - JSON
    alert(json.message); 
}


 <action name="myaction" class="actions.MyAction">
    <result name="success" type="json"/>
    <result name="error" type="json"/>
</action>         <!-- for JSON result, don't forget to extend json-default in the package-->
```

**Status**

```
$.ajax({
...
success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
   if(jqXHR.status==200){
       alert('success');
   }else if(jqXHR.status==201){
       alert('failure');
   }
}


<action name="myaction" class="actions.MyAction">
    <result name="success" type="httpheader">
         <param name="status">200</param>
    </result>
    <result name="error" type="httpheader">
         <param name="status">201</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

(Jquery Ajax Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Do I need to create any getters and setters for that `sataus` param ?
I have tried the Third case. But no luck I will post my entire code now.

Comment: I dont Know whats wrong in Your answer I am able to do that using following code  
`statusCode:{500:function(){alert("The document number is alredy Exist");},
                   200:function(){alert("Good Work !! You can proceed.");}`

Comment: @looser your answer is just another variation of jquery Ajax. Anyways, I'm glad you solved it.

Comment: @looser: "+1 for your contribution". I can't see the +1.

Comment: @looser `+1` means upvoting.